Torch runtime cannot be installed when Visual Studio is an elevated 'Admin' mode
I'm having trouble with ML.NET tool in Visual Studio 2022:

Torch runtime cannot be installed when Visual Studio is an elevated 'Admin' mode.

This is the error, and it only happens with ML.NET's Train Mode, everything else is still working normally.
enter image description here

Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

I suggest you provide more context, otherwise you are reliant on users with a specific use case.   I've source what your installing and steps to install.  Whether it's an extension or method of insulation.

I've run it under the correct admin, I've fixed it according to the admin instructions but to no avail.  It seems the problem is in Torch Runtime.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder/issues/2737
The problem was resolved by upgrading version

Install Ml.net outside of visual studio.
Exit out of all Visual Studio instances. Run the Visual Studio Installer and select Modify. In the Installation details, on the right, at the bottom in Extensions select ML.Net Model Builder 2022 and install the tool.
